# Lock–Key protection Mechanism

Tags: security

According to the book " Operating Systems Concepts " , 9th edition, page 638, we have a describtion for the Lock–Key  protection Mechanism :

> The lock–key scheme is a compromise between access lists and
> capability lists. Each object has a list of unique bit patterns,
> called locks. Similarly, each domain has a list of unique bit
> patterns, called keys. A process executing in a domain can access an
> object only if that domain has a key that matches one of the locks of
> the object.

Still, I need to understand this approach more. As we know, we can access an object with some access right, if we are given permission for this access right. This means that for object O1, a domain D1 could have read access only. So this means that for each object we could have a list of locks, every lock corresponds to a certain access right in a certain domain, is this correct?

Comment: How does your question relate to Ubuntu?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.